# How to implement Class Polynomial C#

Tags: c#

Again I am doing my homework and I need help.

I need to display the polynomial as a single variable, which method is better for this? I thought to work with as a dictionary `(key: 5x, value ^ 3)`, but I ran into a problem (two identical keys, I get an error). I would appreciate any suggestions.
Here is what I tried to do:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace Polinom
{
    class Program
    {
        class Polynom
        {
            // Dictionary Method
            public static Dictionary<int, string> MyDic(int i)
            {
                Dictionary<int, string> dic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
                int num;
                string  x;
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nInput a coeffs: ");
                    num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Input degree: ");
                    x = Console.ReadLine();
                    dic.Add(num, x);
                }
                return dic;
            }
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How many polynomial member?");
            try
            {
                int i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Dictionary<int, string> dic = Polynom.MyDic(i);
                // Get Key Collection
                ICollection<int> keys = dic.Keys;
                Console.WriteLine("Your Polinom is: ");
                foreach(int j in keys)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0}{1}", j, dic[j]);
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong code");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you supply more detail on the problem you're trying to solve. Currently there is not enough information here to give a constructive answer.

Comment: Try : List<Tuple<decimal,decimal>> polynomial, where the two decimal values are the coefficient and the exponent.

Comment: I would use a List<doubleOrDecimal>. If you actually have a key to look them up you may use a Dictionary<string, List<doubleOrDecimal>>. Use the indexer of the list as the power.

Comment: The task is : Develop a “polynomial” class for working with polynomials as one variable and overload for the class
operations allowed for working with polynomials (addition, subtraction, multiplication).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework

Comment: Seems like you'd key on the exponent and then when you find you already have a entry for that exponent you'd just add the coefficient to it, thus reducing the polynomial as you go.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin Homework questions aren't expressly off-topic. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/334823#334823

Comment: If you need a "dictionary" with duplicate keys, the data type you are looking for is a [lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Thank You, I will check it out.

Comment: Guys I am not asking for giving me solution , I ask just to direct me in the right direction. Thank You for understending.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just make polynomials their own object? Then make a list of them if you need to.

```
public class Polynomial
{

    public int Coefficient {get;set;}
    public int Exponent {get;set;}

    public Polynomial(int coef, int exp)
    {
        Coefficient = coef;
        Exponent = exp;
    }

}
```

Then for lists:

```
List<Polynomial> polyList = new List<Polynomial>();
```

Comment: Though I like the idea here, the execution could use some work. The basic problem is that **things should be named according to what they are**. In your system you have called a *polynomial term* `Polynomial` and then you've said that a polynomial is a list of polynomials.  Make sure that names reflect reality. Make your class called `Term`, and then make a class `Polynomial` that contains a `List<Term>`, and now your type system reflects the business domain of the program rather than working against it!

Comment: Thank You Eric, I'll take it in account.